# Print all subdirectories of $d that have reading access for all users

Tags: linux

I need to print all subdirectories of $d that have reading access for all users... so I start with `ls -l $dir` and then I tried to continue like this: `ls -l $dir | grep "-r*"` but it does not recognize the output of the first command as the input of grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-P` flag and provide a Perl regex:

```
ls -l $dir | grep -P "^-r"
```

This will list all files that begins with "-r", which is what you want.

Comment: good! but i know noticed that it prints all files under $dir and i only want all subdirectories... how should i print only the subdirectories?

Comment: @UFCInsider You can `ls -l $dir/*` instead.

Comment: i must start with `ls -l $dir |`

Answer (score 0):

```
find "$dir" -type d -perm -o+r
```

Judging by the discussion so far, what you're doing currently is most likely getting you directories readable by their *owners*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all subdirectory you should use `ls -lR $dir`, then you have to filter with `grep | grep '^dr[w-][x-]r[w-][x-]r[w-][x-]'`, I preferred to implement this last condition more safe specifying the required char and char "r" in the 1,4,7 position. 
In details condition `[list]` means that you can replace it with only one char specified into the list. There is different way to declare the list of char:

```
[abc] // you can replace with one between a or b or c.
[1-7] // you can replace with one char between 1 2 3 4 5 6 or 7.
[c-f] // you can replace with one c d e or f.     
[[:digit:]] // you can replace with one numeric char. 
[[:upper:]] // you can replace with one uppercase char.
[[:lower:]] // you can replace with one lowercase char.
```

Only directory and subdirectory:

```
ls -lR $dir | grep '^dr[w-][x-]r[w-][x-]r[w-][x-]'
```

Directory, subdirectory and files:

```
ls -lR $dir | grep '^-r[w-][x-]r[w-][x-]r[w-][x-]'
```

I do not find anything about `-P` flag it into the `man grep`.